# How To Sort a List<T>?

Tags: c#

```
public class Checkit
{
  public string ID{ get; set; }
  public string b{ get; set; }
  public string c{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a class and I use also `List<T>` like this:

```
Checkitcs = new Checkit();
List<Checkit> Lst_Ch = new List<Checkit>();
```

and I want to sort by `ID`. For example:

```
Lst_Ch[1] = { ID=123 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[2] = { ID=124 , b='afgasf' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[3] = { ID=523 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[4] = { ID=123 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[5] = { ID=523 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[6] = { ID=105 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
```

and I want to Sort like that:

```
Lst_Ch[6] = { ID=105 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[1] = { ID=123 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[4] = { ID=123 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[2] = { ID=124 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[5] = { ID=523 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
Lst_Ch[5] = { ID=523 , b='afasfa' , c='afagas'}
```

How can I sort this List?

Comment: The code you've got won't even compile, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: I try to group by but i cannot achieve. Like this: 'Lst_Ch.GroupBy(x => x.ID)'

Comment: [`Enumerable.OrderBy` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and `List<T>` Indexes in this collection are zero-based.

Comment: I'm assuming the b value for the first item with ID 124 is wrong? (Apart from the compilation problems you'll have)

Answer (score 1):

Your example code will not compile, because the `ID` property of your class needs to be an `int` instead of a `string` and you need to put double quotes around your string values, like this:

```
public class Checkit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<Checkit> Lst_Ch = new List<Checkit>();
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 123,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 124,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 523,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 123,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});        
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 523,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});
Lst_Ch.Add(new Checkit
{
    ID = 105,
    b = "afasfa",
    c = "afagas"
});
```

Second, to sort the list, do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Checkit> query = Lst_Ch.OrderBy(l => l.ID).ToList();
```

The variable `query` is now your sorted list, which you can use elsewhere, loop through, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it not compile because he is using single quotes instead of double quotes also?  I didn't give you the -1 though

Comment: @Harrison - updated my answer, accidentally hit key combo that submitted my answer before I could finish entering it.

Comment: @Karl it just example I know it is not compile. Thanks for your answer, I can use it

Comment: @jeremmyp - if you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept it and up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Use Linq to sort it and create a new `List<T>`. Something like:

  ```
  List<Foo> unsortedList = CreateAnUnorderedList() ;
  List<Foo> sortedList   = unsortedList.OrderBy( x => x.DateCreated )
                                       .ThenBy(  x => x.Id          )
                                       .ToList()
                                       ;
  ```
- You can sort it in place. Something like:

  ```
  List<Foo> myList = CreateAnUnorderedList() ;
  myList.Sort( (x,y) => x.Id < y.Id ? -1 : x.Id > y.Id ? +1 : 0 ) ;
  ```

Alternatively, you can use an ordered collection, like `SortedList<T>`.